# Excel sumif to match the current hour

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a table that has hours listed in column B an an expected # of cycles in column D. i need to have it sum the expected cycles for everything up to the current hour in cell D21. I can not for the life of me get it to work. the code i tried is below along with a picture of the table to help understand what i am trying to do.

```
=SUMIF(B8:B20,"<=HOUR(time())", D8:D20)
```

[image]

so if it is 10:00 AM the sum in cell D21 should be 24. in the image i just had `=sum(D8:D20)`

What did i do wrong in my formula that it inst working?

Comment: What actual format is column B? Is it really a date/time with just the time showing? In that case, you're comparing a time/date value with an integer (hours extracted from `time()`) which doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @lurker it is just a time format with no date

Comment: Try: `"<=TIME(HOUR(NOW()),0,0)"`

Comment: @DavidZemens that returns a zero value when i add that to my formula

Comment: OK, still, you are comparing a time format to a number format, which is comparing apples and oranges, so to speak.

Comment: @lurker so is it not possible? w/o changing the format of column b

Comment: The formula @DavidZemens is showing is correct. You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: @lurker no mine wasn't quite correct, but this might be: `=SUMIF($B$8:$B$12,"<="&TIME(HOUR(NOW()),0,0),$D$8:$D$12)`

Comment: wtf that worked idk what i was doing wrong

Comment: The ampersand/formula concatenation was important :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this should perhaps best go as a comment, but I don't have that privilege yet. But to get the current hour (in excel 2013 that is) you write:

```
=SUMIF(B8:B20; "<="&HOUR(NOW());D8:D20)
```

Comment: =SUMIF(B8:B20; "<="&HOUR(NOW());D8:D20)

Comment: @David Did you try it? Seems to work on my numeric time/date values in excel 2013?

Comment: did you ensure column B holds Hour values rather than entire time values?

Comment: @MLind it contains the entire time value with no date

Comment: @Vbasic4now: Did you check that =Value(B9) give 7.0? That's what Hour(now()) would give at 7 AM in the morning.

Comment: @MLind it returns .3333333

Comment: @DavidZemens Note that we try to compare integers that are the result of =Hour(X) where X is a date/timevalue

Comment: I revised your answer with the correct formula from your first comment.

Comment: @Vbasic4now: Then you are comparing datevalues in column B to integer hours returned by Hour(now()). Try writing the Hours as ordinary integers in column B!

Comment: @MLind the numbers are coming from another table and have to be in this format. do you think there is another way to accomplish what i am trying to do?

Comment: Yes, take the numbers in col B not directly from the other table but like this =Hour(corresponding cell in ohter table)

Comment: @Vbasic4now or keep col B as it is but make a new (maybe hidden one) that is =Hour(B) and use that in the sumif.

Answer (score 1):

Most likey your "1am" is in reality 0.0416666666666667, which is year 0 + 1/24 of a day.

You need to divide your hour(**now()**) by 24 before comparing

Comment: Don't forget also that you can evaluate a formula step by step (Formulas ribbon). This will help you to get the values you're comparing.

Comment: it is just telling me my formula has errors and wont run it, its not like its just giving me wrong values

Comment: how would i incorporate that into my formula?

Comment: That would be
=SUMIF(B8:B20; "<="&HOUR(NOW())/24;D8:D20)